# Choosing a distributed shared memory solution

Tags: java, architecture, nosql, distributed-caching

I have a task to build a prototype for a massively scalable distributed shared memory (DSM) app. The prototype would only serve as a proof-of-concept, but I want to spend my time most effectively by picking the components which would be used in the real solution later on.

The aim of this solution is to take data input from an external source, churn it and make the result available for a number of frontends. Those "frontends" would just take the data from the cache and serve it without extra processing. The amount of frontend hits on this data can literally be millions per second.

The data itself is very volatile; it can (and does) change quite rapidly. However the frontends should see "old" data until the newest has been processed and cached. The processing and writing is done by a single (redundant) node while other nodes only read the data. In other words: no read-through behaviour.

I was looking into solutions like [memcached](http://memcached.org) however this particular one doesn't fulfil **all** our requirements which are listed below:

1. The solution must at least have **Java client API** which is reasonably well maintained as the rest of app is written in Java and we are seasoned Java developers;
2. The solution must be totally **elastic**: it should be possible to add new nodes without restarting other nodes in the cluster;
3. The solution must be able to handle **failover**. Yes, I realize this means some overhead, but the overall served data size isn't big (1G max) so this shouldn't be a problem. By "failover" I mean seamless execution without hardcoding/changing server IP address(es) like in memcached clients when a node goes down;
4. Ideally it should be possible to specify the degree of data overlapping (e.g. how many copies of the same data should be stored in the DSM cluster);
5. There is no need to permanently store all the data but there might be a need of post-processing of some of the data (e.g. serialization to the DB).
6. **Price**. Obviously we prefer free/open source but we're happy to pay a reasonable amount if a solution is worth it. In any way, paid 24hr/day support contract is a must.
7. The whole thing has to be hosted in **our data centers** so SaaS offerings like Amazon SimpleDB are out of scope. We would only consider this if no other options would be available.
8. Ideally the solution would be *strictly consistent* (as in CAP); however, *eventual consistence* can be considered as an option.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have a look at [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com). It is pure Java, open source (Apache license) highly scalable in-memory data grid product. It does offer 7X24 support. And it does solve all of your problems I tried to explain each of them below:

1. It has a native Java Client.
2. It is 100% dynamic. Add and remove nodes dynamically. No need to change anything.
3. Again everything is dynamic.
4. You can configure number of backup nodes.
5. Hazelcast support persistency.
6. Everything that Hazelcast offers is free(open source) and it does offer enterprise level support.
7. Hazelcast is single jar file. super easy to use. Just add jar to your classpath. Have a look at screen cast in main page.
8. Hazelcast is strictly consistent. You can never read stale data.

Comment: Thanks, we are actually using Hazelcast in one of our other projects. Honestly speaking, I was expecting somebody to hint on using something like Project Voldemort and give some insight how well does that scale (for the requirements I have mentioned), mainly because Hazelcast seems to be a wide-purpose library whereas project(s) like Voldemort are specific map-based DSMs. I am of course not trying to say Hazelcast won't cope with the load - this needs to be measured and tested.

Comment: Just realized you're one of the authors of Hazelcast. Whoops :)

Comment: Yes I am one of the authors:) 
Hazelcast Distributed Map is a specific Map based DSM. For the scalability please see our 100 node cluster demo at http://java.dzone.com/articles/running-hazelcast-100-node.

Comment: Unfortunately, this project has been cancelled, but I am going to accept this question as it looked like closest to what I was asking for.

Comment: Hazelcast looks like the way to go, Fuad :)

Comment: Great, specific answer, Fuad (+1). I thaught, however, that Hazelcast is AP + eventually consistent (http://code.google.com/p/hazelcast/wiki/FAQ).

Comment: Ok, found the details you have written at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hazelcast/UK6E-iKdHS0, Fuad. That is a good explanation, whereas I find your above statement `Hazelcast is strictly consistent` a bit oversimplified...

Comment: Fuad, what assurance can you provide that Hazelcast is strictly consistent?

Comment: How will Hazelcast address the serious issues that https://jepsen.io/analyses/hazelcast-3-8-3 reports?

Comment: @DerekMahar please see our official response: https://blog.hazelcast.com/jepsen-analysis-hazelcast-3-8-3/

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to use [Redisson](http://redisson.org) - Redis based In-memory Data Grid for Java. Implements (`BitSet`, `BloomFilter`, `Set`, `SortedSet`, `Map`, `ConcurrentMap`, `List`, `Queue`, `Deque`, `BlockingQueue`, `BlockingDeque`, `ReadWriteLock`, `Semaphore`, `Lock`, `AtomicLong`, `CountDownLatch`, `Publish / Subscribe`, `RemoteService`, `ExecutorService`, `LiveObjectService`, `SchedulerService`) on top of [Redis](http://redis.io/) server! It supports master/slave, sentinel and cluster server modes. Automatic cluster/sentinel servers topology discovery supported also. This lib is free and open-source.

Perfectly works in cloud thanks to AWS Elasticache support

Answer (score 3):

Depending of what you prefer, i would surely follow the others by suggesting Hazelcast if you're towards AP from the CAP Theorem but if you need CP, i would choose [Redis](http://redis.io/)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Terracotta's JVM clustering, it's OpenSource ;)
It has no API while it works efficent at JVM level, when you store the value in a replicated object it is sent to all other nodes.
Even locking and all those things work transparent and without adding any new code.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to checkout Java-specific solutions like Coherence: http://www.oracle.com/global/ru/products/middleware/coherence/index.html

However, I consider such solutions to be too complex and prefer to use solutions like memcached. Big disadvantage of memcached for your purpose is lack of record lock it seems and there is no built in way to replicate data for failover. That is why I would look into the key-value data stores. Many of them would satisfy your need completely.

Here is a list of key-value data stores that may help you with your task:
http://www.metabrew.com/article/anti-rdbms-a-list-of-distributed-key-value-stores
Just pick one that you fill comfortable with.

Answer (score 2):

I am doing a similar project, but instead targeting the .NET platform. Apart from the already mentioned solutions, I think you should take a look at [ScaleOut StateServer](http://www.scaleoutsoftware.com/pages/products/scaleout-stateserver.php) and [Alachisoft NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/index.html). I am afraid neither of these alternatives are cheap, but they are a safer bet than open source for commercial solutions according to my judgement.

1. Both provide Java client APIs, even though I have only played around with the .NET APIs.
2. StateServer features self-discovery of new cache nodes, and NCache has a management console where new cache nodes can be added.
3. Both should be able to handle failovers seamlessly.
4. StateServer can have 1 or 2 passive copies of the data. NCache features more caching topologies to choose between.
5. If you mean write-through/write-behind to a database that is available in both.
6. I have no idea how many cache servers you plan to use, but here are the full price specs:
   [ScaleOut StateServer](http://www.scaleoutsoftware.com/pages/evaluate-purchase/pricing.php)
   [Alachisoft NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/buy.html)
7. Both are installed and configured locally on your server and they both have GUI Management.
8. I am not sure exactly what strictly consistent involves, so I'll leave that for you to investigate..

Overall, StateServer is the best option if you want to skip configuring every little detail in the cache cluster, while NCache features very many features and caching topologies to choose from.

Depending on the behaviour of data towards the clients (if the data is read many times from the same client) it might be a good idea to mix local caching on the clients with the distributed caching in the cluster (available for both NCache and StateServer), just a thought.

Comment: Thanks Herber, I will definitely look at these offerings. The project has been paused for a while, but I promise to "accept answer" on my choice of selection when the time comes. Currently Hazelcast seems to be the way to go, mainly due to its nativeness to Java. Will keep you posted.

Comment: I can see the benefits of using a solution that's already used in your organization. Good luck with your project, and let me know if I can provide any more help.

Answer (score 2):

The specified use case seems to fit into Netflix's [Hollow](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/netflixoss-announcing-hollow-5f710eefca4b). This is a read-only replicated cache with a single producer and multiple consumers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tought about using a standard messaging solution like [rabbitmq](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) ?
RabbitMQ is an open source implementation of the [AMQP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol).

Your application seems more or less like a Publish/subscribe system.
The Publisher node is the one that does the processing and puts messages (processed data) in a queue in the servers. 
Subscribers can get messages from the server in various ways. AMQP decouples the producer and the consumer of messages and is very flexible in how you can combine the two sides.

Comment: This is an interesting approach, but do these messaging solutions are able to keep the messages for non-determined amount of time? I had an impression that messaging framework only cares about a message until it gets delivered, right? While here we have data that might or _might_not_ change and the subscribers should be still able to retrieve it after, say, few hours. Also, the opposite is also necessary - do these messaging solutions support data flushing as most DSMs do?

Comment: If I remember well in rabbitmq queues can also be persistent, meaning messages are kept on disk, and they are safe to crashes. First thing that comes to mind for flushing is having dedicated consumers who only do that: wait for message saying cleanup, flush all the queues and then write the new data. It's been some time since I read the specs so there might be better solutions.

Comment: I'm afraid anything disk-related is not an option as I need minimum latency here. Also I doubt rabbitmq would allow me to do O(1) arbitrary lookups like map-based DSMs do. But thanks for your input anyway!

Comment: RabbitMQ is not suited for this purpose, that said, it doesn't require disk access.